# Burninate [letter]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, meta-tags

I recently came accross the [letter](/questions/tagged/letter) tag.

- It has not tag wiki.
- Looks like a meta tag for everything that involves characters/letters
- 0 followers
- Only 104 questions.

Usages include:

- Device letters for Windows
- as synonym for character
- specific letters for a language (Greek letters)

I believe it should be burninated.

Comment: I should really search better. Anyway, just close it as duplicate, the other request might get some attention.